# SQL Conversion failed to insert parameter -date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to put parameter date into temp table. 
But always get Conversion failed.

Is there any advice about datetime Conversion ?? 
Thanks

```
--***********************************************************************************************************
Declare @dblQuote as varchar(4)
Declare @sDate as varchar(10)

Declare @sSQL_tmpHCDetails nvarchar(max)


Select @dblQuote = ''''

-- #tmpHCDetails  ***********************************************************************************************************
Declare @StartDate  datetime ='7/6/2015 12:00:00 AM'

IF IsNull(Object_Id('tempdb..#temptb'),0) <> 0 DROP TABLE #temptb; 

create table #temptb
(
 sDate  datetime
);


set @sSQL_tmpHCDetails='INSert into #temptb ( sDate ) '
set @sSQL_tmpHCDetails=@sSQL_tmpHCDetails+ 'select Convert(DateTime,'+ @dblQuote + @StartDate + ' 23:23:59 ' + @dblQuote + ',108)'



exec @sSQL_tmpHCDetails

select * from   #temptb
```

Comment: did you try to execute this piece of code without dymanic `select Convert(DateTime,'+ @dblQuote + @StartDate + ' 23:23:59 ' + @dblQuote + ',108)`?

Comment: from query above you got more then _varchar(10)_  try to change it to _varchar_ (20) etc.

Comment: `@StartDate` is a `DATETIME`, `@sSQL_tmpHCDetails` is a string. You cannot mix the two together in the line `set @sSQL_tmpHCDetails=@sSQL_tmpHCDetails+ 'select Convert(DateTime,'+ @dblQuote + @StartDate + ' 23:23:59 ' + @dblQuote + ',108)'`. You must convert `@StartDate` to a `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution....

Declare @dblQuote as varchar(4)
Declare @sDate as varchar(10)

Declare @sSQL_tmpHCDetails nvarchar(max)

Select @dblQuote = ''''

-- #tmpHCDetails  ***********************************************************************************************************
Declare @StartDate  datetime ='7/6/2015 12:00:00 AM'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@StartDate,107)

IF IsNull(Object_Id('tempdb..#temptb'),0) <> 0 DROP TABLE #temptb;

create table #temptb
(
 sDate  datetime
);

set @sSQL_tmpHCDetails='INSert into #temptb ( sDate ) '

set @sSQL_tmpHCDetails=@sSQL_tmpHCDetails+ 'select Convert(DateTime,'+ @dblQuote + **CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@StartDate,107)** + ' 23:23:59' + @dblQuote + ',108)'

**exec(@sSQL_tmpHCDetails)**

select * from   #temptb